# Aliasing object methods by pre-pending "get" to use in a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have an `ArrayList` of custom beans. I'd like to use the jstl `join` function with an `ArrayList` by calling the `toArray` method of the `ArrayList` and then overriding `toString` on the objects it contains.

It's been said that there is nothing really stopping me from extending classes to include a "get" for methods/properties that I would like to expose to JSP.

So, for this example:

```
class MyArrayList extends ArrayList
{
  public Object[] getToArray()
  {
     return this.toArray();
  }
}
```

Good idea?

I've been creating classes like this with re-usability in mind which has me wondering: Is there a library in existence that simply extends a lot of core Java classes by aliasing useful methods to have a "get" version so they can be used in JSP?

Of course, this may be another case of me not quite grasping some fundamental concepts with regard to JSP but I see it as pure inconvenience that only bean type classes with the "get" style method names can be used in a JSP page. If so, please feel free to tell me why a library like this is a bad idea. Basically, if a library like I describe doesn't exist, why not?

Comment: Does EL 2.2 which allows you to call arbitrary methods (available in Tomcat 7 onwards) get you what you need? e.g. ${someListObject.toArray()} which should return an array.

Comment: @MarkThomas It certainly sounds like it would. I'm stuck (for now) with 6. Thanks, this is a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to your concrete functional requirement, you could create a custom EL `join()` function which takes a `List` or `Collection`.

E.g.

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.Collection;

public final class Functions {

     private Functions() {}

     public static <E> String join(Collection<E> collection, String separator) {
         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

         for (E element : collection) {
             if (builder.length() > 0) {
                 builder.append(separator);
             }

             builder.append(element);
         }

         return builder.toString();
     }

}
```

Which you register as follows in a `/WEB-INF/functions.tld` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>Custom Functions</short-name>
    <uri>http://example.com/functions</uri>

    <function>
        <name>join</name>
        <function-class>com.example.Functions</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String join(java.util.Collection, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

Which can finally can be used as

```html
<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://example.com/functions" %>

${f:join(bean.list, ', ')}
```

Or if you happen to have [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) already in the classpath, just delegate to it instead.

```xml
    <function>
        <name>join</name>
        <function-class>org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String join(java.util.Collection, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
```

As to your initial question, I would rather not add custom public methods to an custom implementation of an already existing interface and rely on that custom implementation.

Comment: This is a good solution and a good alternative to my "aliasing" class in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EL 2.2 - which allows you to call arbitrary methods (available in Tomcat 7 onwards) - should get you what you need. e.g. ${someListObject.toArray()} which should return an array